# Can I run an event when image has loaded using setAttribute("src") and getAttribute("data-src")?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website, I have created a lightbox that shows an image until the actual image is loaded. This is my code for loading the image:

```js
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";}
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        slides[slideIndex-1].setAttribute("src",slides[slideIndex-1].getAttribute("data-src"));
}
```

```html
<img class="slides" src="img/global/lazyload/lazyload.gif" data-src="img/home/Material_1.png">
```

Essentially I replace the src with data-src. However, I wish to run a fade-in effect once the data-src has loaded using CSS. How would I go about implementing that? Is there an on complete, or on load "event" that I can use. Is it possible to do with the only javascript?

Right now, the src image quickly snaps to the size of the actual image for a brief moment and then replaces the data-src.

Answer (score 2):

The event that you are after is the `load` event on the DOM element.

The easiest way to transition is to have one element fade into view on top of another element. The following example does it by placing the image on top of a background image and performing a CSS transition.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('img');

img.addEventListener('load', e => {
  if (img.src !== 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?placeholder') {
    img.classList.add('show');
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-src'));
}, 500);
```

```css
.container, .container img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.fade-in {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?placeholder')">
  <img class="fade-in" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?placeholder" data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?actual" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great way to solve the problem. However, I have read that src"" should always be included when working with images. Is there no way to just add a fade in after the data-src is loaded? On this for example: `<img class="slides" src="img/global/lazyload/lazyload.gif" data-src="img/home/Material_1.png">`

Comment: I updated the snippet. I personally don't think it matters about the `src`, but you could add the placeholder image as the `src` and only trigger the fade in behavior if it isn't the load of the placeholder image.